# What is the right Ukrainian counterpart for a "questionnaire"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Until recently I have had no doubt that the right Ukrainian counterpart for ***`questionnaire`*** is ***`опитувальник`***.

***`Опитувальник`*** is widely used under Ukrainian business and legal context.
There are 41 documents with the word ***`опитувальник`*** used disclosed under the [search result](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/main) at the web of the Verkhovna Rada of Ukraine.

E.g. The Resolution of the National Securities and Stock Market Commission on the [Regulation on Conducting Financial Monitoring by Stock Market Participants](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0551-16?nreg=z0551-16&find=1&text=%EE%EF%E8%F2%F3%E2%E0%EB%FC%ED%E8%EA&x=11&y=8) uses ***`опитувальник`*** for a ***`questionnaire for a client`***.

Other examples of the usage of the word ***`опитувальник`*** are official translations into Ukrainian of the [Recommendation by the Commission 94/390/EC On Taxation of Small and Medium Enterprises](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/994_970?nreg=994_970&find=1&text=%EE%EF%E8%F2%F3%E2%E0%EB%FC%ED%E8%EA&x=9&y=8) and of the [Statute of the Group of States on Counterterrorism Efforts](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/994_144) etc.

Thus, ***`опитувальник`*** sounded absolutely natural to my ears.

Nonetheless, a couple of days ago I received a document by the Ministry of Infrastructure of Ukraine named ***`запитувальник`***.

Having checked the usage of a new and unknown word with the web of the Verkhovna Rada of Ukraine I was surprised to find out it was indeed used, although only in one document by the Ministry of Health Protection, namely the O[rder on the Instruction on Clinical Trials of Medicinal Products](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0830-00/page?text=%E7%E0%EF%E8%F2%F3%E2%E0%EB%FC%ED%E8%EA) (currently non-valid).

But I was even more astonished when I discovered neither of the two mentioned words in the Dictionary of the Ukrainian Language :)

Instead, there are two other words with a similar meaning:

> [ЗАПИТА́ЛЬНИК,](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapytaljnyk) а, чол. **Зібрання
>   питань на яку-небудь тему або з якої-небудь галузі знань і т. ін.;
>   питальник**.

and

> [ПИТА́ЛЬНИК](http://sum.in.ua/s/pytaljnyk), а, чол. **Перелік питань з
>   якої-небудь наукової теми, з певної навчальної дисципліни**. *До
>   серйозних досягнень науки [діалектології], на жаль, поки що не можна
>   віднести того важливого, що стосується укладання відповідних
>   «питальників»* (Розвиток науки в УРСР.., 1957, 83).

Moreover, the Dictionary of the Synonyms by Karavansky offers ***`запитальник`*** and  ***`питальник`*** as synonyms to ***`анкета`***.

Documents search at the VRU's web discloses 35 documents with the word ***`запитальник`*** and none with ***`питальник`***.

**So kindly advise on a dictionary, if any, to "legitimize"** `опитувальник` **and/or**  `запитувальник` **not only at the legal level but also at the linguistic one.**

Answer (score 3):

Наведені нижче джерела дать підстави стверджувати, що і "опитувальник", і "анкета" є допуститимими варіантами перекладу слова "Questionnaire".

1. Слово "анкета" є у Словнику і має таке визначення:

> [АНКЕ́ТА,](http://sum.in.ua/s/anketa) и, жін. Бланк установленої форми для запису в ньому певних біографічних та інших відомостей.

2. І "опитувальник", і "анкета" вживається у схожих контекстах: "формувати Анкету клієнта", "зазначені в опитувальнику клієнта" у документі за першим посиланням із запитання — [Regulation on Conducting Financial Monitoring by Stock Market Participants](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0551-16?nreg=z0551-16&find=1&text=%EE%EF%E8%F2%F3%E2%E0%EB%FC%ED%E8%EA&x=11&y=8).
3. "Анкета" вживається в вікіпедії при описі [методології опитування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) і загалом зустрічається там 23 рази. Там же 2 рази згадується і "опитувальник", і *жодного* разу не згадується "запитувальник". Також у якості україномовної версії статті "[questionnaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Questionnaire)" вікіпедія пропонує саме [анкетування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

Google Translate також надає "анкета" як варіант перекладу "questionnaire".

Comment: Анкетування - це метод, між українською і англійською вікіпедіями не повна відповідність.

Comment: Пані Оксана шукає спосіб довести *законність* або зворотнє для вживання слів *`опитувальник`* і *`запитувальник`* в значенні *`questionnaire`*.

Answer (score 1):

Віктор Шапар, «Сучасний тлумачний психологічний словник: близько 2500 термінів», с. 296:

> **ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК** — методики,  що  розробляють  питання,  на  які  клієнтові  слід  відповісти,  або  ж  твердження,  з  якими  він  повинен  погодитися  або  не погодитися.  Розрізняються  такі  типи  опитувальників:  1)  відкриті;  2)  закриті;  3)  анкетні;  4)  особистісні.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК АНКЕТНИЙ (опитувальник-анкета) — <…>.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК ВІДКРИТИЙ (опитувальник типу відкри­того) — <…>.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК ЗАКРИТИЙ (опитувальник типу закри­того) — <…>.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК ОСОБИСТІСНИЙ — <…>.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК ОСОБИСТІСНИЙ БАГАТОФАЗНИЙ МІННЕСОТСЬКИЙ (ММРІ) — <…>.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК ОСОБИСТІСНОЇ ОРІЄНТАЦІЇ (Personal Orientation Inventory, POI) — <…>.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК РИС ОСОБИСТОСТІ — <…>.
>
> ОПИТУВАЛЬНИК ТИПОЛОГІЧНИЙ — <…>.

[«Словник української мови» у 20 томах](https://sum20ua.com/?page=1328&wordid=216641):

> КЛАСТЕРУВА́ТИ <…> Науковці кластерували дані **опитувальника** щодо дитячої грамотності (з наук. літ.).

Також [«Словник української мови» у 20 томах](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=1239&page=52) має:

> **АНКЕ́ТА**, и, ж. Опитний лист для запису в ньому певних відомостей. Дехто з наших літературознавців і критиків звертався до мене з листами і з анкетами, прохаючи в мене відповіді на різні питання про моє життя, працю і про інше (С. Васильченко); Комісар читав анкету. Вона була коротка і ясна, як і саме життя Андрія Голуба (В. Кучер); * Образно. Працювать, працювать, безумовно! Кожній хвилі нема ж вороття! Ні! Я зовсім іще не заповнив золотої анкети життя (В. Сосюра).

Answer (score -1):

Word "опитувальник" is somewhat wrong and is underlined even in this field where I am writing, should be "опитувач". It is derived from verb "опитувати", but "запитувальник" is wrong as well :) and should be "запитувач" - this word is derived not from a verb, but from a noun "запит" and should be translated as requestor. (not totally sure on this, because my English is pretty basic...)

Comment: *опитувач* - це особа, а тут йдеться про документ.